How to correctly retrieve artifacts from another job if the requesting job is triggered manually?
Using GitLab, I'm simulating the following behavior in my QA env:

Commits (or merges into) to main, triggering build job to build the Docker image
Merges main into stable (prod)
Creates (manually) a tag from stable, triggering a job that retags the built image with the new tag and pushes it to AWS ECR

With my current .gitlab-ci.yml, upon commit on main, a pipeline is created containing only the build_qa job. Upon tag creation after merge on stable, a new pipeline is created for the push_to_qa job.
The problem is: the new pipeline can't find the artifact when I try to docker load, even though I'm using dependencies.
This is the .gitlab-ci.yml so far:
variables:
  DOCKER_REGISTRY_QA: foo
  DOCKER_REGISTRY_PROD: bar
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: us-east-1
  APP_NAME: test-pipeline-tags
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  IMAGE_VERSION_QA: latest
  IMAGE_VERSION_PROD: latest
  IMAGE_TAG_QA: "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_QA/$APP_NAME:$IMAGE_VERSION_QA"
  IMAGE_TAG_PROD: "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_PROD/$APP_NAME:$IMAGE_VERSION_PROD"
  IMAGE_FILE_NAME: qa_latest.tar
  IMAGE_DIR: image
  IMAGE_PATH: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/$IMAGE_DIR/$IMAGE_FILE_NAME"

stages:
  - build_qa
  - push_qa

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "main"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^v(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/

build_qa:
  stage: build_qa
  image: 
    name: amazon/aws-cli
    entrypoint: [""]
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "main"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - amazon-linux-extras install docker
    - aws --version
    - docker --version
    - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_QA
    - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_QA
    - aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $DOCKER_REGISTRY_QA
  script:
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_TAG_QA .
    # tars the image and exports it to the artifact folder:
    - mkdir $IMAGE_DIR
    - docker save $IMAGE_TAG_QA > $IMAGE_PATH
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 2 hour
    paths:
      - $IMAGE_PATH

push_to_qa:
  dependencies:
    - build_qa
  stage: push_qa
  image:
    name: amazon/aws-cli
    entrypoint: [""]
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^v(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/'
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - amazon-linux-extras install docker
    - aws --version
    - docker --version
    - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_QA
    - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_QA
    - aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $DOCKER_REGISTRY_QA
  script:
    # loads image from artifact
    - docker load -i $IMAGE_PATH
    # creates a new image tag based on the created tag:
    - export NEW_IMAGE_TAG_QA="$DOCKER_REGISTRY_QA/$APP_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_TAG"
    # retags the image to the created tag:
    - docker tag $IMAGE_TAG_QA $NEW_IMAGE_TAG_QA
    - docker push $NEW_IMAGE_TAG_QA

This is the full message:
$ docker load -i $IMAGE_PATH
open /builds/path/to/proj/test-pipeline-tags/image/qa_latest.tar: no such file or directory
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1

I was trying without the $CI_PROJECT_DIR before, and I thought that using it would be the fix but no success. The artifacts do exist and they haven't expired.
